# Lang's Representation of Third Isomorphism Theorem

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I wanted to ask what is the intuition behind the commutative diagram representation of the third isomorphism theorem in Lang's Algebra, page 17. Namely, the one that states
$$(G/K)/(H/K)\approx G/H$$

Where G is a group, and $H\supseteq K$ are normal subgroups of G.

I apologize for not drawing the commutative diagram. I'm too tired to look up the code for the diagram. But I am asking those of you who have a copy of the copy of the book to help me out. The gist of the diagram are two exact sequence one of which is 
$$0\longrightarrow H\longrightarrow G\longrightarrow G/H \longrightarrow 0$$
$$0\longrightarrow H/K\longrightarrow G/K\longrightarrow G/H \longrightarrow 0$$

And there are canonical maps from the top sequence to the bottom sequence, both of which are exact.

Answer (score 0):

You can reduce the fraction $G/H$ to $(G/K)/(H/K)$ and preserve its "value"

$$ G/H \overset{\cong}{ \rightarrow} (G/K)/(H/K)$$

Comment: I already know what the purpose of the third isomorphism is for. What I don't understand is the commutative diagram representation of the theorem.